# SQL Query to fetch records that are present in one table but not in another table

Tags: fetch

I have two tables employeedetails and employeesalary with common column empid.
How can i fetch records that are present in one table but not in another table.

I have tried using :
select ed.*,es.* from employeedetails as ED LEFT  JOIN employeesalary as ES
ON ed.empid = es.Empid

select * from employeedetails ED WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from employeesalary ES WHERE ED.Empid=ES.Empid)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lmy6.png)

Comment: Did those queries give you results? If so, what did you get, and what did you want instead? The first one misses a clause to only return those that only have rows on the left side, but the second query I feel like is exactly what you're asking for. What was wrong with it?